# Cloud Endpoint Builder in Eclipse gives "TypeNotPresentException" if an API method returns a List with class from another library

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to create a very simple Cloud API. My API class looks like this:

```
package com.cloudtest.my;

import java.util.List;

import com.cloudtest.lib.ClassInLibProj;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;

@Api(
        name = "test",
        version = "v1",
        scopes = {EndpointsConstants.EMAIL_SCOPE},
        clientIds = {EndpointsConstants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, EndpointsConstants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
        audiences = {EndpointsConstants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE}
)

public class CloudClass {

    public List<ClassInLocalProj> listLocal() {
        return null;
    }

    public List<ClassInLibProj> listRemote() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have a class `ClassInLocalProj` which is the generic type of the first Api method, `listLocal()`, in the above class and it is working fine since it is a class within the current project.

I also have a class `ClassInLibProj` in a library project as the generic type of the second Api method `listRemote()`. This does not work because I get an error from the Google Cloud Endpoints Builder in my Markers tab stating: "There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.cloudtest.lib.ClassInLibProj not present".

Both `ClassInLibProj` and `ClassInLocalProj` are simple empty classes for testing purposes and I have included   the library project in Eclipse under Java Build Paths, Projects tab.

Can anyone resolve this?

Thanks.